# How does master/slave switch happen in liferay(6.2, tomcat8, multicast ) cluster?

Tags: cluster-computing, liferay-6, tomcat8

We have configured our liferay cluster environment to run the scheduler jobs only in master node based on a property check. Lately the master/slave switch is happening which is causing scheduler not to execute the jobs.

This is the log we observed in tomcat logs during the time of switch.

```
INFO  [Incoming-2,liferay-channel-transport-0,node117281][BaseReceiver:88] Accepted view [node1] [node1]

 INFO  [Incoming-2,liferay-channel-control,node1][BaseReceiver:88] Accepted view [node1] [node1]

 WARN  [Incoming-2,liferay-channel-control,node1][ClusterRequestReceiver:261] Unknown uuid xxxxxxx from node2
[Incoming-1,liferay-channel-control,node1][ClusterRequestReceiver:261] Unknown uuid xxxx from node2
```

We are setting a property XXXXX in portal-ext properties of both the nodes. Scheduler jobs will be executed only in that node where that property value is true or when one of the nodes is down.

Switch(master/slave) happens automatically. If the node which has the said property value as false and is up, then it won't execute scheduler jobs. Hence we have to monitor scheduler activity regularly.

Clarification:

Team has assumed schedulers get triggered in both the nodes in a clustered environment which is not true. Hence they had set a property which decides on which node scheduler job has to get executed. We are going to remove it in production.

I would like to know the in what all the scenarios master/slave switch happens.

Comment: I don't understand *"master node based on property check"* (is this custom code?) and *"during the time of the switch"* or the relevancy of the log output. Do you switch something actively? I'd expect the cluster master node to be automatically elected among the cluster nodes.

Comment: Hi Olaf, thank you for the reply. We are setting a property in portal-ext properties of both the nodes and executing the jobs only in the node where that property value is set to true.

Comment: portal-ext.properties changes require a server restart to become active. And setting a property in the context of calling out master/slave doesn't make sense without seeing what you do. Please add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to this question (edit the question to clarify, don't comment)

Comment: Hi Olaf, thanks for the quick reply. No, that property was not for calling the master/slave. I have edited the question with more details. We have removed that property now. Previously there were easy pointers like connection exception when the switch used to happen. I have gone through the source code but couldn't figure out the root cause.

Comment: The question now says that you're doing this properties based, the comments say you don't. As this is a question about your custom code, please add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of how you set up the scheduler jobs that are only supposed to run on the master node. And if there's custom code to figure out which one is master, add that as well. Make it reproducible. Thanks